# A word that includes plants and fungi, but not animals

Tags: single-word-requests, scientific-language, biology, plants

I am working on a project which includes information about plants and fungi. It would be very helpful for me if there a word that means ***plants-and-fungi***, but I'm not sure there is. "***Flora***" only includes plants, but "***biota***" includes animals.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118721/discussion-on-question-by-joaquim-dsouza-a-word-that-includes-plants-and-fungi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer is "no", however "flora" is probably the best option, as it can include fungi in specific contexts (e.g. "intestinal flora").

Comment: If the work is scholarly, a precising definition of 'flora' is required. Sadly, [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/flora)'s first given definition is too narrow ('all the plants of a particular place or from a particular time in history') while [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flora)'s second sense is too broad ('2: plant, bacterial, or fungal life'). Both being in common use, it could be misleading to use the term (though an ad hoc stipulative definition could be stated). I'd say the three-word term is the best there is. // There being 5/6 Kingdoms in

Comment: traditional taxonomies of living things, it's unlikely that there exist 15 say terms for binary groupings, 20 for ternary etc. Admittedly, almost all plants and many fungi are outwardly somewhat similar, so one might expect an older term to survive here, one that could be recycled.